# Python 2 to 3 conversion: 'TypeError: missing required positional argument:'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2to3

I'm new to Python (and to stackoverflow) and my first task is to convert an energy flow simulation program from Python 2.7 to Python 3.6 and get it running on 3.6. I already used the 2to3 converter and solved some other errors but now I'm hitting a wall with this error, not knowing if it's an error of the existing program or if I use the wrong syntax etc. The code apparently worked in Python 2. 
If I additionaly put in **house_atrs** in the function it will start the function but throws a long list of other errors. So I hope for your help and would like to understand the reason of this error in 3.6 compared to 2.7.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Users\hs\workspace\selfsuffbat\vpp_interface_refpool_noPCR_161026.py",
  line 85, in <module>
    analyze(sim_atrs, output_folder, output_subfolder, economic=True, binary=True)
TypeError: analyze() missing 1 required positional argument: 'output_subfolder'
```

Code of vpp_interface_refpool_noPCR161026.py:

```
from pool_builder import pool_df
from main import simulate
from main import analyze    

if __name__ == '__main__':

  output_folder = 'output/data/'
  output_subfolder = 'refpool_noPCR'
```

[...]

```
  simulate(house_atrs, sim_atrs, sim_args, output_folder, output_subfolder)
  analyze(sim_atrs, output_folder, output_subfolder, economic=True, binary=True)
```

Code of the function analyze() in main.py:

```
def analyze(sim_atrs, house_atrs, output_folder, output_subfolder, economic=True, economic_standalone=False, binary=False):
  print('started analyzing')
  analysis(folder=output_folder, subfolder=output_subfolder, fileindata=None, firstloop=True, binary=binary,
         usegreengrey=sim_atrs['use_greengrey'], usedegradation=sim_atrs['use_degradation'],
         uselocalbalance=sim_atrs['use_localbalance'], providePCR=sim_atrs['provide_pcr'],
         usethermal=sim_atrs['use_thermal_load'])
  if economic:
    assert economic_standalone is False, 'Set "economic" to False and "economic_standalone" to True for standalone calculations'
    economic_calc(output_folder, output_subfolder, year=2015, useselfsufficiency=sim_atrs['use_localbalance'])

  elif economic_standalone:
    assert economic is False, 'Set "economic" to True and "economic_standalone" to False for pooled calculations'
    economic_standalone_calc(output_folder, output_subfolder, year=2015, useselfsufficiency=sim_atrs['use_localbalance'])

  print('finished analyzing')

if __name__ == '__main__':
  pass
```

Comment: The error is quite descriptive. Seems you need to pass ``house_atrs`` as the second argument, which would then make it 4/4 positional arguments, where you're currently only passing 3/4.

Comment: This problem has nothing to do with the Python 3 migration--it's obvious that the code wouldn't work in Python 2 either.

Comment: Unfortunately your edit makes this question quite different and no information to address the new one is given (as error message).

Comment: I'm wondering because all other old (2.7) interfaces have the same line of code without house_atrs in analyze(). So I get a step further but I don't know if this is intended. Anyway thank you very much for your help to a total beginner.